# Profiling memory usage of tornado apps

Tags: python, ubuntu, debugging, memory, tornado

I have a large tornado application that I have to migrate from ubuntu 14 to ubuntu 16. In my tests I have noticed that on ubuntu 16 memory usage increased and I want to find out why.

I have used [memory profiler](https://github.com/fabianp/memory_profiler) to track the memory usage. You can see the results in the image, [image: ubuntu 14 vs ubuntu 16] with black is memory usage on ubuntu 16 and with blue is on ubuntu 14.

**Python versions used:**

- Python 2.7.6 -> ubuntu 14
- Python 2.7.12 -> ubuntu 16

**Tornado version used:** 4.5.1

I don't know how to find the problem and what to do next. If you encountered a similar situation please share the steps that helped you to find the root cause.

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by `"I don't know how to find the problem ..."`? What problem are you referring to? Higher memory consumption can (and most of the time does) mean better, faster performance.

Comment: I want to find out what causes this memory increase. In my case the the performance of the application is the same.